# Ajustar div img al margen derecho bootstrap

Tags: html, css, bootstrap, div, dompdf

Por favor ayuda.
Estoy intentando ajustar una imagen al margen derecho con bootstrap en un documento que tengo en pdf pero no he logrado.

En html si ajusta bien con align="right", pero en pdf no que puedo hacer.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

```
<div class="row" class="font t-8">
    <div class="col-xs-4">
        <label>Ciudad: <?php echo $datos_cabecera["ciudad"]; ?></label>
    </div>
    <div class="col-xs-4">
        <label>Tipo bonificación: <?php echo $datos_cabecera["tipo_bonificacion"]; ?></label>
    </div>
    <div class="col-xs-4" align="right">
        <img width="100" src="<?php echo base_url();?>../imagenes/logoami.png" class="">
    </div>
</div>
```

Si le doy align="right" lo saca del margen.
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: Que se supone que es esta doble declaracion de `class` ?? -> `<div class="row" class="font t-8">`

Comment: Por favor, agrega todo el codigo para crear un [mre]

Comment: Prueba a añadir un margin-right y align="right" . Otra opción sería float: "right";